# Changing Margins on thesis

Tags: margins

Quick question to anyone who has used this LaTeX template:

http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Any ideas on how to change the left margin to get more words onto one page?

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate as the updated version of the template is incompatible with the answers below. The more recent question shows this.

Answer (score 2):

From the file `vmargin.sty`, margins can be set with

```
\setmargins{leftmargin}{topmargin}{textwidth}{textheight}%
       {headheight}{headsep}{footheight}{footskip}
```

or with

```
\setmarginsrb{leftmargin}{topmargin}{rightmargin}{bottommargin}%
         {headheight}{headsep}{footheight}{footskip}
```

Define the parameters (leftmargin, topmargin, etc) and put this command just before `\begin{document}` in the file `main.tex`.

From `vmargin.sty`:

Example:

A4 paper, left margin 30mm, top, right, and bottom margin 20mm
    each, no headers or footers:

```
\setpapersize{A4}
\setmarginsrb{30mm}{20mm}{20mm}{20mm}{0pt}{0mm}{0pt}{0mm}
\pagestyle{empty}
```

The same settings would result with:

```
\setpapersize{A4}
\setmargnohfrb{30mm}{20mm}{20mm}{20mm}
```

Comment: While the answer is good, I'd suggest avoiding `vmargin` that's not compatible with other packages, notably `atbegshi` that's needed for instance by `pdfpages`. It's better to use `geometry` for setting the page parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the `layout` package ?

If not, try this, but I cannot guarantee you that it will work...

Just put `\usepackage{layout}` in the preamble, and put `\layout` where you want (I do it right after \begin{document}).
It'll display a page with the margins, and the names of the margins under the picture...

You can resize every margin like this :

Set
`\setlength{"Name of the margin wo want to resize"}{"length"}` in the preamble.

Here is an example of the `\layout` :
[image]

You just have to resize the right margin...

I hope it'll work with thesis, I haven't tried yet...

Comment: I'm curious, did it work ?

Comment: Using your direction, I have the following errors: `(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex.latex.tools/layout.sty) Runaway argument? {document] \layout \frontmatter ./main.tex:40: Paragraph ended before \begin was complete. <to be read again> \par I.40 ?`

Answer (score 0):

With this template you should be able to set the margins in the `Thesis.cls` file.

In the file there is a section for margins as follows

```
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   %    MARGINS
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \setmarginsrb  { 1.5in}  % left margin
                            { 0.6in}  % top margin
                            { 1.0in}  % right margin
                            { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                            {  20pt}  % head height
                            {0.25in}  % head sep
                            {   9pt}  % foot height
                            { 0.3in}  % foot sep
```

In the version I used it was on lines 74-84 of the file. If you edit these margin settings it should change the settings on the template.