# Undefined Control Sequence - setmarginsrb

Tags: errors

I wanted to modify the margins of my LaTeX document.
Here's the commande I wrote:

```
% Margins
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setmarginsrb{4.5cm}{2.5cm}{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
```

I set "0pt" to the last 4 parameters because I didn't want to change their values from default.

The command seems to work when I compile, but I have an error:

> The control sequence at the end of the top line
>   of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
>   misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
>   spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
>   and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Also it created a new page at the beginning of my document with "4.5cm2.5cm3.5cm2.5cm0pt0pt0pt0pt".

Code: http://pastebin.com/X6d7jFPe

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your code is not compilable. Please improve and minimize it. Some notes: Load `hyperref` last, don't load packages (`array`) twice, don't use `vmargin` but `geometry`, use `xcolor` instead of `color` or use none, as `eso-pic` loads the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also [an answer concerning the use of the package vmargin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108578)

```
% arara: pdflatex 

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{vmargin} % needed for the command \setmarginsrb (I would recommend geometry here)
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell} % removed second call of array
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath} % I recommend mathtools here (not needed in your example)
\usepackage{eso-pic} % loads xcolor
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{color} % xcolor is newer
\usepackage{hyperref} % in most cases to be loaded last

\pagestyle{fancyplain} \chead{}\lhead{\textit{The Creative Workers}} \rhead{\emph{\textit{FPSDesigner}}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}     

% Margins
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setmarginsrb{4.5cm}{2.5cm}{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}     
    \thispagestyle{empty}     
    \vspace*{2cm}     
    \begin{center}
            test
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```